# use Google Sheets QUERY to sum column where = x on a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets in it,
I want to summarize the daily results by date.
I'm trying to use the query sum function to summarize everything since I wasn't able to do it with arrayformula.

but I'm not able to do it with a query as well.
I don't want to just copy-paste the sum function from each row to the next I want to just type the date I need in column A and get all the results in the different columns.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZsKXw32ycO_5KGD2I-Ug_GmqSIB_Z-D3Z1jlGd6fpTE/edit?usp=sharing

link to sheets.

getting the data from the database sheet.
I want to display the data-oriented by date and sumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for just 1 row you can simply do this and then drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TO_TEXT(DataBase!A:A), DataBase!B:E},
 "select sum(Col5) 
  where Col1 = '"&TO_TEXT(A2)&"' 
  label sum(Col5)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

if array is needed then use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY(DataBase!A:E,
 "select A,sum(E) 
  where A is not null
  group by A
  label sum(E)''", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]